# how to prevent useSelector DRY?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I am building a project using typescript and react, with Redux Toolkit.
Now I find that I need to write sometime the same selectors again and again.
for example `const userRole = useAppSelector((state)=> state.user.role)`,
I want a method to write it once and export it, is there a way to make this
more modular?
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom hook

```
const useUserRole = () => useAppSelector((state) => state.user.role)
```

And then use it like this, inside a component or inside another custom hook:

```
const role = useUserRole()
```

Answer (score 0):

You literally write a selector function.

```js
export const selectRole = (state)=> state.user.role
```

And then

```js
const userRole = useAppSelector(selectRole)
```